# Unity - mix parameter override with normal resolution

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

How do I go about specifying only one parameter in a constructor, whilst injecting the rest as normal in Unity?

e.g.

```
public MyContentStore(string contentPath, IFileSystem fileSystem)
{
}
```

I want to be able to specify the content path at runtime, but have the file system injected automatically by the registered type. I can't seem to mix **ParameterOverride** with **ResolvedParameter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to specify the content path at runtime

I guess this means during resolution. It should work out of the box you don't need to mix anything. Just register your type without any other flavor and then during resolution override the parameter you want to

```
IUnityContainer uc = new UnityContainer();   
uc.RegisterType<IFileSystem, FileSystem>();
uc.RegisterType<MyContentStore>(); 
var ms = uc.Resolve<MyContentStore>(new ParameterOverride("contentPath", "123"));
```

---

On the other hand, if you would like to specify argument during registration it won't be possible as you need to specify every single argument.